# In Pokemon Red/Blue, can you buy the bike before you get the voucher?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

In the original Pokemon games, the bike costs a ridiculous amount of money. So after first encountering it you keep playing the game until you come across a man who has a bike voucher. My question is, can you instead earn enough money to purchase the bike, and get it that way as opposed to using the voucher?

Comment: Remember that Pokémon isn't like other RPGs where you get money by fighting monsters. Not including fighting the Elite Four over and over, there's a finite amount of money available in the game. Since without the bike you're limited to the first few cities, that finite amount of money is even smaller, so even if you could get a million bucks, you still wouldn't be able to buy the bike.

Comment: @JackM: Not having the bike doesn't limit your progress; Cycling Road can be bypassed by traveling south from Lavender to Fuchsia instead.

Comment: @JackM: Actually, at that point in the game you gain access to meowth, who learns that coin move, which provides infinite cash income.  Later you gain access to the casino, where you can make coins, but TMs, and then sell the TMs, for an even slower source of infinite income.

Comment: there is also the famous item duplication glitch but I dont recall if you can actually do everything to complete this at this stage....but if I recall you cannot have the required number of cash as this value was limited as well I believe...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is impossible, the bike costs  1,000,000, but you can only hold 999,999.

> The Bike Shop has a store in Cerulean City, which sells Bicycles produced by the company. Designs range from a plain city bike to fast mountain bike; however the player only ever gets one: the Bicycle. It can be bought for 1,000,000, or exchanged for a Bike Voucher. However, as only 999,999 can be obtained at any time, there is no way to buy a Bicycle without a Bike Voucher. The Pokémon Fan Club Chairman in Vermilion City will give out his Bike Voucher, making this the only viable way to get the item.

Source: [Cerulean City](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Cerulean_City)

Comment: I wonder if the ability to make the transaction is coded into the game, or if it's simply some redundant menu?

Comment: @Nelson The move Pay Day allows you to get money from any battle, including wild Pokémon battles, and you can always re-fight the Elite Four and get money from them. A more complicated method is to win in the Game Corner and trade coins for TMs, which you can then sell. And, of course, selling items duplicated by Missingno, but that's a glitch.

Comment: @Nelson The well known MissingNo glitch also maxes out the item count in your sixth item slot, so you can get infinite nuggets that way and get max cash easily.